# I will apply for a schengen visa and I do not want to tell my employer about it, I know he will refuse. What should I do?

Tags: visas

I am all set to have my Euro trip, have proper documents for everything, and invitation etc. But I do not have the Letter of Leave approval from my employer. I do not want to tell about this to him and instead take a simple leave when my visa arrives. What should I do in this situation?

Comment: Do you need to tell your employer about the reason/destination for the trip? If you can take a “simple” leave once you have a visa, what's stopping you from taking it now and getting a letter confirming that?

Comment: @Relaxed: you might be surprised, but some countries require that applicant provides a letter from employer with mandatory company blank, all standard identification details, mentioning applicant's position, vacation dates and that the letter is intended for obtaining a visa. For example, this is a requirement when [Ukrainian applies for Italian visa (item 3, "certificate of employment")](http://italy-vms.com.ua/document-requirements-for-tourist-visa/). In this case the applicant just have to let his employer know that he is going to travel abroad.

Comment: @RomanR. I am not surprised and I don't think this contradicts my comment. My point was: Can't you get a letter specifying exactly that (where you work, etc. and the fact you are allowed to go on leave from this date to this date) but without telling your employer specifically what you will do during your vacation? Maybe it's not possible, I really don't know, but it seems worthwhile to explore this option.

Comment: The poster's question is about not letting employer know that he's going to apply for a visa. The fact of request of such letter/certificate from employer (esp. but not necessarily when the requirement states that such letter must mention that it is intended for a consulate) immediately reveals the plans the poster wants to keep in secret.

Comment: @RomanR. Certificate of employment is asked everywhere for a Schengen application. But, from experience, I don't think you need a Leave approval,(as the OP mentions) just a letter mentioning your employment details containing start date, posting etc

Comment: Example of Italian requirements per link above says "confirmation of the position maintenance after the end of the trip" which - in my understanding - essentially the same as leave approval. Either way, the only fact of request for such letter might reveal the plans. The OP might clarify the details, but in my understanding one needs to contact the consulate with the question about replacing this letter with something else. Otherwise employer will know the plans. More to say, such letter might be followed by a call to employer to clarify the details.

Comment: I would make this an answer except that it's entirely opinionated: I have seen this type of enquiry lots, they are centralized in Africa and particularly the south Asian subcontinent and seem to occur where the person is female and subject to cultural restrictions on mobility (eg a chaperone) and the person worries about reprisals when word gets back to her family. In extreme cases, the individual is hoping to abscond from a forced marriage, or pregnant and wanting to avoid FGM for the baby,  but more commonly mobility. There is no satisfactory answer without lots of details.  "Too Broad"