# Will the Schengen visa consulate call my work place to verify if I have taken a leave for my intended vacation?

Tags: visas, schengen

Will the Visa Consulate call and check at my work place if I have applied for a leave and if I should be allotted a Schengen visa or not?

Comment: Perhaps you would be better off updating [your original question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/73470/i-will-apply-for-a-schengen-visa-and-i-do-not-want-to-tell-my-employer-about-it) instead of breaking the entire context into pieces. Also, it makes sense to specify which country you are to apply from.

Comment: I don't think they check everyone or it is even likely that they would call. It depends on how they estimate the chances the paperwork at all is reliable. However their requirement to provide the documents on company forms with contact information is exactly to enable the option of calling back to re-check the details.

Comment: Well, my original question is will the Visa consulate accept and process my documents if the leave letter is missing. I will present my employment letter and salary slips to support my employment though. So if the VISA people call at my work place, he might not say things in my favour. I want a leisure trip and I will come back. So is there anything that I can do here?

Comment: @Maddy Still, it would be better to add this to your other question and clarify what has you so concerned. Generally speaking, if they call at all, it would be to verify the accuracy of the information submitted (i.e that you genuinely work where you say you work), not to inquire about your moral character or ask your boss' opinion about anything else.

Answer (score 2):

You will apply for a Schengen visa and want to know what further checks will be made after a decision is reached.

Documentation and eligibility checks are made during the assessment stage. The issuer stops making checks once a decision has been made and will not initiate further checks

The possibility remains open however that they may attempt to contact you after a decision is made...

- An auditor discovered a clerical error on your application like the
  wrong kind of visa was issued, or the dates were transcribed
  incorrectly.
- The reverse. An auditor determined that you were refused and should
  not have been and so they need your passport again to put a visa in
  it.
- One of the national authorities wants to take prejudicial action
  against your visa, like an arrest warrant was issued in your name and
  the consulate wants to revoke your visa.

For these types of situations [the data protection rules](http://ec.europa.eu/justice/data-protection/) are engaged so they would only try to contact you directly and speak with you directly.  They would not contact your employer unless you gave their details as your own contact details.

Also note that the consulate is not the only pathway that information can reach your employer regarding your whereabouts.

Finally, as others have pointed out in comments, you need to disclose any secondary agendas before people can come forward with substantive information.